# How can I merge two different graphics from corrplot

Tags: r, r-corrplot

I generated two different graphics which have different labels, is it possible two merge it?

```
library(corrplot) 
par(mfrow=c(1,2)) 
col<- colorRampPalette(c("#78CB65","#EBF6DF","#AEDAAA")) 
corrplot(as.matrix(samp4), is.corr = FALSE, type = 'lower', method = 'color', addCoef.col = 'black', number.cex=0.50,
                 col=col(11),
                 tl.col = "black",
                 tl.cex = 0.8,
                 title = "OrthoANI")
corrplot(as.matrix(ddh2), is.corr = FALSE, type = 'upper', method = 'color', addCoef.col = 'black', number.cex=0.50,
             col=col(11),
             tl.col = "black",
             tl.cex = 0.8,
             title = "ddh")
```

[image]

I would like two merge it like this
[image]

I tried making only one data from ddh2 and samp4, but the problem is that the threshold and values are different, so the label has to be different
thanks

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but that seems like a bad idea. This makes it look like it's one plot and the x and y axes of the plots don't match making this really confusing to read.

Comment: The package `ggcorrplot` has `type="lower"` and `"higher"`. ggplot geoms can be easily added, resulting in one plot consisting of 2 triangles

Comment: You can try adding `add = TRUE` as a parameter to the second `corrplot` call.

Comment: I think there's a native functionality to mix different top and bottom halves with `corrplot.mixed()`

Comment: Oh sorry, that probably won't help with two different datasets...